# Error when passing a blob file to send it as e-mail attachment

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to sending a file as e-mail attachment with Google Apps Script, following [this rich answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24343917/sending-a-file-as-e-mail-attachment-with-google-apps-script/24345852#24345852). But instead of a stand alone app, I'm trying to do so within my spreadsheet, using a function like this:

```
function sendAttachment(){
 var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  ScriptProperties.setProperty('emailRequest', 1);
  if(!person_ID) {
    person_ID = getCurrentRow();
    //if the current line is the Column Headers line then ask the user to specify the ID, very rare case.
    if (person_ID == 1) {
      var person_ID = Browser.inputBox("Select one name.", "Click in one row:", Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
    }
  }
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setHeight(400).setWidth(600);
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel(); // you can embed that in a form panel
  var label = app.createLabel("Choose the receiver").setStyleAttribute("fontSize", 18);
  app.add(label);      
  var currentRow = ss.getActiveSelection().getRowIndex();
  var personName = activeSheet.getRange(currentRow, 1).getValue();
  var personNumber = activeSheet.getRange(currentRow, 5).getValue();
  var item1Panel = app.createHorizontalPanel();
  var txt = app.createTextBox().setId("item1").setName("item1").setValue(personName);
  item1Panel.add(app.createLabel("Person:")).add(txt);

  var item2Panel = app.createHorizontalPanel();
  var txt = app.createTextBox().setId("item2").setName("item2").setValue(personNumber);
  item2Panel.add(app.createLabel("Num:")).add(txt);

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(letterSpreadsheetId).getSheetByName("emailsDB");
  var recipientEmailArray = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();  
  var item3Panel = app.createHorizontalPanel();
  item3Panel.add(app.createLabel("Receiver"));
  var listBox = app.createListBox().setName('item3');  
      for(var i = 0; i < (recipientEmailArray.length); i++){
        listBox.addItem(recipientEmailArray[i][0] + ": " + recipientEmailArray[i][2]);
  }
  item3Panel.add(listBox);
  var handlerBut = app.createServerHandler("butSendAttachment").addCallbackElement(panel);
  var but = app.createButton("submit").setId("submitButton4").addClickHandler(handlerBut);
  panel.add(item1Panel)
       .add(item2Panel)
       .add(item3Panel)
       .add(app.createFileUpload().setName('thefile'))
       .add(app.createLabel().setId("answer"))
       .add(but);  
  var scroll = app.createScrollPanel().setPixelSize(600, 400).setTitle("My title 1");
  scroll.add(panel);
  app.add(scroll);
  ss.show(app);


 // var handlerBut = app.createServerHandler("butSendAttachment").addCallbackElement(panel);
 // .add(app.createFileUpload().setName('thefile'));
 // var form = app.createFormPanel();
 // form.add(panel);
 // app.add(form);
  ;
}

function butSendAttachment(e){
  var recipientEmail = e.parameter.item3;
  var fileBlob = e.parameter.thefile;
  Logger.log("file blob = " + fileBlob);
  recipientEmail = recipientEmail.split(':')[1];
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var person_ID = getCurrentRow();
  var columns = getRowAsArray(sheet, 1);
  var personData = getRowAsArray(sheet, person_ID);  
  var sender = actAuthor + " \n          " + position;
  var name = personData[0];
  var motherName = personData[1];
  var title = "my title";
  var message = my mesage";
  var confirm = Browser.msgBox('Send email','Are you sure?', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
  if(confirm=='ok'){
//    MailApp.sendEmail(recipientEmail, title, message, {attachments: [fileBlob]});
    MailApp.sendEmail(recipientEmail, title, message, {attachments: [fileBlob]});   
    var app = UiApp.createApplication().setHeight(150).setWidth(250);
    var msg = "An email was sendo to " + recipientEmail;
    app.setTitle("E-mail send!");
    app.add(app.createVerticalPanel().add(app.createLabel(msg)));
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    doc.show(app);
  }
  else {
      return;
  }
}
```

But I get this error: `Execution failed: Invalid argument: inlineImages (line 77`. Line 77 is this:

```
MailApp.sendEmail(recipientEmail, title, message, {attachments: [fileBlob]});
```

I've read [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app?hl=it-CH#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)) I tried several argument variations. I conclude that fileBlob is `Null`. Why? How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

the fileUpload widget works only in a form parent widget and using a doGet/doPost structure.

That's written somewhere in the doc but right now I don't remember exactly where (I'look for it later)

But actually I guess you can build such a structure from within your spreadsheet, just change the names of your functions and use a formPanel as main widget. Don't forget also that you don't need a handler anymore and must use a submitButton widget.

EDIT : how silly I am ! its written in the first line in [the widget's doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/file-upload) !!! ;-)

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to implement that (replacing `verticalPanel` for `formPanel`)